# Numpy transformation to normal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, normalization

I have an array of data. I checked if it was normally distributed:

```
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import mstats
from scipy.stats import normaltest

Data = []
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    line = line.strip()
    Data.append(float(line))
print scipy.stats.normaltest(Data)
```

The output was: (36.444648754208075, 1.2193968690198398e-08)

Then, I wrote a small script to normalise the data:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
fileopen = open(sys.argv[1])
UntransformedArray = []
for line in fileopen:
    line = float(line.strip())
    UntransformedArray.append(line)
TransformedArray = (UntransformedArray - np.mean(UntransformedArray)/np.std(UntransformedArray))
NewList = TransformedArray.tolist()
for i in NewList:
    print i
```

And then I checked for normality again using the first script and the output was 
(36.444648754209595, 1.2193968690189117e-08).

...the same as the previous score, and not normally distributed.

is one of my scripts wrong?

Also, should I mention that the average of my data is 0.056, the numbers range from 0.014 to 0.171 (85 observations), I'm not sure if the fact that the numbers are so small matters.

A sample of the untransformed and transformed data:

Untransformed:

```
0.055
0.074
0.049
0.067
0.038
0.037
0.045
0.041
```

Transformed data:

```
-2.13696814254
-2.11796814254
-2.14296814254
-2.12496814254
-2.15396814254
-2.15496814254
-2.14696814254
```

Edit 1:

When I edit the code slightly to account for parenthesis being in the wrong place:

```
TransformedMean = (UntransformedArray - np.mean(UntransformedArray))
TransformedArray = (TransformedMean/np.std(UntransformedArray))
NewList = TransformedArray.tolist()
for i in NewList:
    print i
```

The output I get it different:

Example:

```
-0.0385683544143
0.705333390576
-0.273484694937
0.431264326632
-0.704164652563
-0.743317375984
```

However, when I check for normality:
(36.444648754241328, 1.2193968689995659e-08)

It is still not normally distributed (and is still the exact same score as the other times)?

Edit 2:

I then tried a different method of normalising the data:

```
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import boxcox

Data = [(float(line.strip())) for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
scipy.stats.boxcox(Data)
```

I get the error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'float'

EDIT 3: Due to comment from user, the problem was understanding the difference in normalising values, versus normalising a distribution.

Edited code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

fileopen = open(sys.argv[1])
UntransformedArray = []
for line in fileopen:
    line = float(line.strip())
    UntransformedArray.append(line)

List1 =  np.log(UntransformedArray) 
for i in List1:
    print i
```

Checking for normalisation:
(4.0435072214905938, 0.13242304287973003)

(works in this case, depending on skewness of the data).

Edit 4: Or using a BoxCox transformation:

```
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import boxcox
import numpy as np

Data = []
for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
    line = line.strip()
    Data.append(float(line))

data = scipy.stats.boxcox(np.array(Data))
for i in data[0]:
    print i
```

Check for normalisation: (2.9085877478631956, 0.23356523218452238)

Comment: Don't you have a parenthesis problem in the TransformedArray calc? ( UntransformedArray - np.mean(UntransformedArray) ) /np.std(UntransformedArray)

Comment: This is what I have:TransformedArray = (UntransformedArray - np.mean(UntransformedArray)/np.std(UntransformedArray)) and it seems to run without complaining? Don't get any error about parenthesis?

Comment: Arithmetic division (/) has not the same priority has the minus (-) operation. Thus, you are dividing the mean/std, and then only after the subtraction is applied. I believe your parenthesis are misplaced there.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the script slightly (see edit). Is it possibly something wrong with the checking for normality script? The reason I ask is that now I've given the checking for normality script two different lists, (for example, my original transformed output, where all the numbers start with -2.XXX, and in my edit, where the numbers are e.g. 0.43, -0.7 etc), and I still get the exact same output from checking for normality script?

Comment: Re. `boxcox`:  Try `scipy.stats.boxcox(np.array(Data))` (and add `import numpy as np` at the top of your script if you don't already have it).  By the way, `scipy.stats.boxcox(Data)` works in newer versions of `scipy`.  What version are you using?  Run `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

As expected, subtracting the mean and rescaling to unit variance does not change the shape of the distribution. `normaltest` correctly returns the same output in both cases, telling you that your data is *not* normally distributed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas. But to be more precise: You are standardizing the distribution of your array! This does not change the shape of the distribution! You might want to use the numpy.histogram() function to get an impression of the distributions!

I think you have fallen prey to the confusing double usage of 'normalization'. On the one hand, normalization is used to describe standardization of variables (getting variables on the same scale - this is what you did). On the other hand, normalization is used to describe attempts of changing the shape of a probability distribution (the scipy.stats.normaltest() is used to check the shape of such distributions). One easy strategy to try to get a distribution more normally is to use a log transformation. numpy.log() might do the trick here, but only if the original distribution is not too skewed.

Comment: This was really useful thank you, particularly in the clarification of the understanding. I have made an edit with the updated code that I used.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem. My data was not normal like yours and I had to transform my data to a normal distribution. For transforming your data to normal you should use normal score transform by different methods like as it is described [here](http://node101.psych.cornell.edu/Darlington/transfrm.htm). You can also use [these formulas](https://www.statsdirect.com/help/data_preparation/transform_normal_scores.htm). I have written a python code for changing your list of elements to normal distribution as follows:

```
X = [0.055, 0.074, 0.049, 0.067, 0.038, 0.037, 0.045, 0.041]

from scipy.stats import rankdata, norm

newX = norm.ppf(rankdata(x)/(len(x) + 1))
print(newX)

output:
[ 0.4307273   1.22064035  0.1397103   0.76470967 -0.76470967 -1.22064035
-0.1397103  -0.4307273 ]
```

You can see that your new data is completely normal after this transformation as you can see by Q-Q plot:

```
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax4 = plt.subplot(111)
res = stats.probplot(newX, plot=plt)
plt.show()
```